# how upload image in php store in some directory and display it

Tags: php

simple question I am learning php so i want  to give option to user that it uploads the image(using upload button ) and it save in my system directory and my program display it on browser

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Surely a Google search for something like "PHP upload image" will find *something*?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials and guides on Google for this ...

Comment: unfortunatily it works as a single file but when i put it in my project then it dont work what is the problam u expect.?

Comment: its working fine but how it show on tables where my other text data have accured

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1) form.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload (TEST)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="file">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) upload.php

```
<?php
    if(pathinfo("yourdir/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]), pathinfo_extension) != 'jpg') { // and so on...
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "yourdir/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
?>
```

You don't even need to care about the extension, as the browser will display your file as an image if it recons it actually is an image, so you don't have to get mad with exestions. However, for security purposes, it is better to always check it is not a potentially malicious file (php, py, js ...)

Comment: No problem, take time ;-)

Comment: Yeah, enjoy it ;-)